# Why does my recursive SQL (with a CTE) gives me more values than my dataset?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem with a recursive sql.

I have a dataset, here is a sample :

| Top_lvl_article | Prev_Article | Current_Article | Qty | Lvl | Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 80542.296 | 80542.296 | 80542.296 | 1 | 0 | 80542.296 |
| 80542.296 | 80542.296 | 80537.127 | 1 | 1 | 80542.296 ||80537.127 |
| 80542.296 | 80542.296 | 80537.969 | 1 | 1 | 80542.296 ||80537.969 |
| 80542.296 | 80542.296 | 80540.285 | 1 | 1 | 80542.296 ||80540.285 |
| 80542.296 | 80540.285 | 01583.1527-H | 1 | 2 | 80542.296 ||80540.285||01583.1527-H |
| 80542.296 | 80540.285 | 80539.398 | 1 | 2 | 80542.296 ||80540.285||80539.398 |
| 80542.296 | 80540.285 | 80540.05 | 1 | 2 | 80542.296 ||80540.285||80540.050 |
| 80542.296 | 80540.05 | 80540.050U | 1 | 3 | 80542.296 ||80540.285||80540.050||80540.050U |
| 80542.296 | 80540.050U | 80540.092 | 0.001 | 4 | 80542.296 ||80540.285||80540.050||80540.050U||80540.092 |
| 80542.296 | 80540.092 | 80532.395 | 0.023 | 5 | 80542.296 ||80540.285||80540.050||80540.050U||80540.092||80532.395 |

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3191d3a706567affc824bd411d4d3c6c) is the full dataset, if you wanna try.

I want to create a column which is `Current_Article` quantity + `Prev_Article` quantity which is the quantity of father's current article.

So I tried a recursive sql like this :

```
 WITH CTE_Top_levels
     (Lvl,
      Order,
      Top_lvl_article,
      Prev_Article,
      Current_Article,
      Qty
     )
  AS (
select ts.level,
       ts.order,
       ts.top_level_article,
       ts.prev_article,
       ts.Current_Article,
       ts.quantity
  from #t_sample_dataset ts
 where ts.level = 0

 UNION ALL

select ts.level,
       ts.order,
       ts.top_level_article,
       ts.prev_article,
       ts.Current_Article,
       cte.qty + ts.quantity
  from CTE_Top_levels cte
  join #t_sample_dataset ts
    on ts.Prev_Article, = cte.Current_Article,
   and cte.Top_lvl_article = ts.top_level_article
   and ts.level <> 0
  )
```

With this request, I got way more rows than 10 rows (number of rows in my dataset).

I tried to get all the top level inside my CTE and then, trying to read all the children.

First of all, I just want to understand what is wrong in my request, why do I have more than 10 values?

Any help?

**Expected output**

| Top_lvl_article | Prev_Article | Comp_Article | Qty | Lvl | Total_qty | Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 80542.296 | 80542.296 | 80542.296 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 80542.296 |
| 80542.296 | 80542.296 | 80537.127 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 80542.296 ||80537.127 |
| 80542.296 | 80542.296 | 80537.969 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 80542.296 ||80537.969 |
| 80542.296 | 80542.296 | 80540.285 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 80542.296 ||80540.285 |
| 80542.296 | 80540.285 | 01583.1527-H | 1 | 2 | 3 | 80542.296 ||80540.285||01583.1527-H |
| 80542.296 | 80540.285 | 80539.398 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 80542.296 ||80540.285||80539.398 |
| 80542.296 | 80540.285 | 80540.05 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 80542.296 ||80540.285||80540.050 |
| 80542.296 | 80540.05 | 80540.050U | 1 | 3 | 4 | 80542.296 ||80540.285||80540.050||80540.050U |
| 80542.296 | 80540.050U | 80540.092 | 0.001 | 4 | 4.001 | 80542.296 ||80540.285||80540.050||80540.050U||80540.092 |
| 80542.296 | 80540.092 | 80532.395 | 0.023 | 5 | 4.023 | 80542.296 ||80540.285||80540.050||80540.050U||80540.092||80532.395 |

Which is basically current article's quantity + total quantity

Comment: Is your table meant to be formatted like that, or do you have denormalised data which is double pipe (`||`) delimited?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see! I have double pipe. It is supposed to be one column

Comment: can you share the expected output given the provided input? @LouisChopard

Comment: Is that your current query ? It has several syntax error. Few extra comma at the end. Also few column name does not matches with the schema

Comment: Please also show the current output of your query in text and not as image

Answer (score 0):

Just because a comment can not include the whole query string.

Your query with some fixed errors in column names and with added `qty` column in CTE to conform the expected results is

```
WITH CTE_Top_levels
 (Lvl,
  "Order",
  Top_lvl_article,
  Prev_Article,
  Current_Article,
  Qty,
  total_qty
 )
AS (
select ts.lvl,
   ts."order",
   ts.top_lvl_article,
   ts.prev_article,
   ts.Current_Article,
   ts.qty,
   ts.qty
from #t_sample_dataset ts
where ts.lvl = 0

UNION ALL

select ts.lvl,
   ts."order",
   ts.top_lvl_article,
   ts.prev_article,
   ts.Current_Article,
   ts.qty,
   cte.total_qty + ts.qty
from CTE_Top_levels cte
join #t_sample_dataset ts
on ts.Prev_Article = cte.Current_Article
   and cte.Top_lvl_article = ts.top_lvl_article
   and ts.lvl <> 0
) select Top_lvl_article, Prev_Article, Current_Article, Qty, Lvl, Total_qty, "Order"  from cte_top_levels
```

[Look](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b0348d726f8f061ccaf709116e90237e), it works with your sample data.

Comment: It's not working on my full dataset. I added a dbfiddle link just under the dataset sample if you wanna try your code.

Comment: It's not working as you expect because you have duplicate rows with equal `current_article` value, moreover some of them have different `level` value. For example, `80539.866`. You have 5 rows with this value in `current_article`, 3 of them have `level` = 5 and 2 - `level=4`. This value `80539.866` is used in ''prev_article` value in other rows. Your data is inconsistent, that's a problem

Comment: @LouisChopard, is Alexey's solution breaking on more than just your duplicate rows? If so, could you explain in what way it's not working? I independently worked out a solution similar to (but somewhat different from) Alexey's but it also produces odd results around the duplicates and I'm reluctant to post it if it isn't an improvement.